# uiViewController Swift IOS

Tags: swift, uialertview, ios8

I am using swift and have a class called ViewController() that is linked to my storyboard. I am trying to get an alert view to display from another class. I am using the following code however it will not open an alert box. Any Ideas?

```
public class SomeClass {

        func showAlert(title:String, body:String) {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    func showAlert(title:String, body:String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))        
        var vc: ViewController = ViewController()
        vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you're doing or why. And how is this any better than the other answer?

Comment: I saw him getting error when he tries instantiating ViewController. Also, i tried putting Markus's answer in code. It's working for me in my test project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `presentViewController` on your `UIViewController` and pass in your `UIAlertViewController`.

In UIViewController:

> self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

`alert` being your `UIAlertViewController`.

Comment: how can I call that from a class not in the view controller?

Comment: You need a pointer to your view controller in your class. Or if your class returns the UIAlertViewController to your ViewController and you call it from there.

Comment: so I added var view = ViewController() and it throws error